# .NET Core Solution design having issues with reference to old version libraries

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am in process of designing a basic application, where I would need to utilize my existing `.Net` libraries which I have written using `Framework 4.5`

I am trying to design following structure:

```
-CODE
  -Business.csproj
     - TargetFramework - netstandard1.6          
     - ProjectReference - domain.csproj built on .NET 45 framework.
  - WebApi.csproj
     -TargetFramework - netcoreapp1.1    
     - ProjectReference - Business.csproj 
-TEST
  - Business.Tests.csproj
     - TargetFramework - netstandard1.1          
     - ProjectReference - domain.csproj built on .NET 45 framework.  
     - ProjectReference - Business.csproj built on netstandard1.6 framework. 
  - WebAPI.Tests.csproj
     -TargetFramework - netcoreapp1.1    
     - ProjectReference - Business.csproj 
     - ProjectReference - WebApi.csproj
```

**Understanding:**

1. **`Business.csproj`** is targeting framework `netstandard1.6`, as both `.NET Framework (4.5.x)` & `.NET Core` implements
   `netstandard1.6`
2. **`WebApi.csproj`** is targeting framework `netcoreapp1.1` as it is need for ASP.NET Core features &  referencing project
   **`Business.csproj`** built on `netstandard1.6`

Now when try to restore packages - I am getting following errors:

> 1. One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
> 2. Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 supports: portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
>    Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.

Comment: Where do the external libraries come in inside the diagram?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, edited my design.

Comment: I don't think you can reference existing framework libraries in a .NET CORE application. I believe your libraries need to be a .NET Standard library to be used in multiple framework types (Core, vs 4.6, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using project.json then you need to add an imports section to the project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"
    }
  }
```

If you're using .csproj then you need to modify the .csproj file like this:

```
<PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
```